# how to set (programatically) margin for a view?

Tags: swift, uikit

I am new to UIKit. I have a `UICollectionView` within the parent view and it works properly with such constrains

```
...
        addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
...
```

But what I need is to bind this `UICollectionView` to the bottom of the parent view (currently it appears in the center).

In order to do this, I removed top constrain

```
...
        addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
...
```

But the view just disappeared from the screen. Then I tried to add width and height

```
...
        collectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
...
```

but this also didn't help.

I also tried to add margins in order to move the `UICollectionView` to the bottom, but also without success.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

The bottom line is - that I need my collection view to be bind to the bottom of the view.

The last attempt I did is -

```
...
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
...
```

but view takes more space than I need, so I tried to lower the number to 150

```
...
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
...
```

and view vanished...

Something weird is happening:)

Looks like the only way it works is -

```
...
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor, constant: 75).isActive = true
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.heightAnchor).isActive = true
...
```

But I think it isn't proper configuration.

Comment: Can you show a diagram of where you want the collection view to be?

Comment: I doubt that when you merely changed 200 to 150 the collection view vanished. How do you know that it vanished? You might not see anything, but that could be for some other reason (perhaps it is unable to draw any _cells_ that you can see). Give the collection view a bright `backgroundColor` so that you can see where it is. Also, use the _view debugger_ to show you where the views are and why.

Comment: Also a lot depends on a whole lot of _other_ constraints. What `layoutMarginsGuide` is this? What view are you adding this collection view to, as a subview? What constraints are setting the size and position of _that_ view? You have concealed all of the relevant information. If you want help, _show your actual code_. Do not play guessing games with us.

Answer (score -1):

A view has two dimensions. You must specify its position and size, both vertical and horizontal.

When you specified top, left, bottom, and right, in relation to a known superview, you were doing that.

When you took away the top constraint, your view had no height so it vanished.

Adding a height constraint was good, though a height of 80 is quite tiny. But you still need a top or bottom constraint.

Also, you cannot add a width constraint and still keep both the left and right constraints, as they contradict each other.

Basically you just need to make up your mind what you want and say it without ambiguity or self contradiction.